# App Not Pulling Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, core-data

I have Core Data set up for my app. I ran into a problem with the fetch request, but fixed it by specifying the `managedObjectContext` being from the `appDelegate`.

When I do an NSLog, it returns the array count as being 0. Any suggestions on how to debug this? I'm not sure where to start debugging as I'm relatively new.

I know there's data in Core Data, and I think the fetch is going through alright. The entity is named Category, and that's where I'm stuck! Any tips for debugging would be great.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:[appDelegate managedObjectContext]];
[request setEntity:entity];


// Specify how to sort the list
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"cat_name" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSLog(@"%d",[fetchResults count]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You use `[appDelegate managedObjectContext]` in the second line and `managedObjectContext` later. Is that identical? - Check if `managedObjectContext` is nil. Check if `fetchResults` is nil.

Comment: Awesome! Good catch--I forgot to update the second instance of it. updating `NSArray *fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];` with `NSArray *fetchResults = [[appDelegate managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];` fixed it!

Comment: It will also save you a lot of headaches if you use a framework (such as Sensible TableView) when working with Core Data instead of doing everything manually. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple issue was that I was calling `[appDelegate managedObjectContext]` in the second l line, but was only calling `managedObjectContext` for the `fetchResults`.